# how to put button in cell of UItableview in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am having an array to display in an tableview .i need a button in the last+1 cell.means the array having 20 elements i need a button in 21st cell how to do that .i need to give the action to that button also..how to do that tell me the code ...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to manage one more cell than your array element count. So make sure to make the following modifications in the table view datasource implementation :

```
// return the correct row count
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [theArray count] + 1;
}

// detect the last cell and add it a subview
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    ...
    // detect the last row
    if(indexPath.row == [theArray count]) {
        UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        // set the frame and title you want
        [b setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [b setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // set action/target you want
        [b addTarget:self
              action:@selector(theActionYouWant:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
        [cell addSubview:b];
    }
    else {
        // configure a classic cell
    }

    return cell;
}

// the action method
-(void)theActionYouWant:(id)sender {
    // handle the action
}
```

As an alternative, why not just use the whole cell to execute an action ? Use the same mechanism to manage one more cell, set it a custom label, and when you detect the cell is selected, send a message :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([indexPath row] == [theArray count]) {
        // the extra cell is selected, send a message
    }
    else {
        // others cells selection handler
    }
}
```

Comment: tell if any alternative is there.